# Live Chat Trasnscript Record shows staus as 'Blocked' in salesforce. How it is coming as Blocked

Tags: liveagent, pre-chat, embedded-services, livechattranscript, chattranscript

When i request chat, the live chat transcript shows status as 'Blocked'. What will be the solution for this?

Comment: maybe you have created LiveChatBlockingRule which is blocking the chats for customers?you can query and see if you have any [select id,FromIpAddress,ToIpAddress from LiveChatBlockingRule]

Comment: there is no blocking Rule for it. I have checked it

Comment: Vinothini, the status will be set to Blocked if the agent clicked "Block Visitor". Open the Chat Transcript record and check the Chat Transcript Events to Verify.